# Postgres Query Complexity when using hash index and b+ tree index

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing

My table (`user_tran`) has 3 fields "**user_id**", "**transaction_id**", "**time_stamp**"

I hash index `user_id` and `transaction_id` (as I need to do the exact match) and b+ tree index on `time_stamp`

The query is

```
select user_id from user_tran where transaction_id = 1 and time_stamp > now() - 3 days; 

select transaction_id from user_tran where user_id = 1 and time_stamp > now() - 3 days;
```

Does anyone know what is the complexity of this query? I know if we just filter by hash index column, it would be **o(1)** and b+ tree gives **o(lgn)**. But what about combining them together?

Would that be **o(lgn + 1)**?

Also how would the table stored under the hood. Will the DBMS maintain 3 indexes (2 hash and 1 b+ tree) at the same time?

Googled around a little bit, but didn't find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With three indexes like that, the complexity for a query that uses the indexes would be **O(n)** because the only way to combine multiple indexes is a *bitmap and*. Creating the bitmap requires reading the whole index, which is **O(n)**.

So, unless none of the conditions alone is very selective, I'd assume that PostgreSQL would choose a regular index scan on the most selective of the indexes and use the other conditions as a filter. The complexity of such a query is proportional to the percentage of rows that match the index condition (say, **O(1)** if there is only a constant number of rows with `user_id = 1` regardless of the table size).

The ideal indexes for these queries are:

```
CREATE INDEX ON user_tran (transaction_id, time_stamp);
CREATE INDEX ON user_tran (user_id, time_stamp);
```